# Проблема с кодировкой при чтении из файла, записи в файл.

Tags: c, кодировка

Добрый день!
Мне нужно прочитать из файла русский текст, потом редактировать его, добавить другой текст в файл. Как я понимаю, обычный .txt для этого использовать не получится, так как там при открытии фала кодировка каждый раз автоматически устанавливается ANSI.

Пытаюсь реализовать это в документе. Открываю его с кодировкой MS-DOS - все отлично, при записи в документ записывается русский текст, но когда я пытаюсь прочитать текст из этого документа в программе мне русский текст не выводится(выводятся какие-то кракозябры - проблемы с кодировкой, как я понимаю).

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с проблемой или посоветуйте, как лучше реализовать данную часть. (Пишу на Си)

Comment: > при открытии фала кодировка каждый раз автоматически устанавливается ANSI

Не, кодировка обычно вообще не меняется, какие байты лежат в файле, такие и получатся в считанной вашей программой строке. Другое дело, если вы _интерпретируете_ эти байты не как ANSI, а как, скажем, cp1251, возможны всяческие сорта ошибок.

Comment: Но... Ведь если я записываю в обычный текстовый файл (с выставленной кодировкой) программой русский текст, а потом его в этой же программе вывожу - выводятся "кракозябры". Они же и в самом текстовом файле при его открытии...

Comment: @777Julia777: не бывает просто "русского" текста, бывает русский текст в какой-то кодировке. Ваша программа, вероятно, записывает русский текст не в той кодировке, в которой вам нужно. Или выводит на консоль не в той кодировке, в которой консоль отображает.

Попробуйте вот что: (1) запишите в пустой файл текст программой, и посмотрите его текстовым редактором. Попробуйте подобрать кодировку, чтобы было видно русские буквы. (2) выведите текстовый файл на консоль командой `type <имя файла>`. Обычно консоль ожидает кодировку cp866, так что скорее всего вы увидите крякозябры.

Comment: Спасибо)

В самой программе у меня выводятся русские буквы. У меня они не выводятся только если читать их из текстового файла.

А как можно сделать, чтобы в консоли отображался текст в нужной мне кодировке при чтении из файла?

Comment: @777Julia777: попробуйте сменить текущую кодировку консоли при помощи команды [`chcp`](http://citforum.ru/operating_systems/msdos/H13.shtml). Аргументом должна быть кодировка вашего файла -- например, 1251? Не забудьте потом вернуть кодировку назад, а то команды типа dir начнут выводить крякозябры. (Гляньте в любом хорошем текстовом редакторе, в какой кодировке ваш текстовый файл.)

Comment: Неа... Не помогает, вроде..(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[@777Julia777](/users/10499/777julia777)](/users/10499/777julia777), в файлах .txt обычно кодировка cp1251 (она же ANSI). Та же кодировка имен файлов и параметров командной строки. Чаще всего текст в программе (исходнике) тоже в ней.

А вот консоль (по умолчанию) осуществляет ввод-вывод в кодировке cp866 (она использовалась в MSDOS). Из-за этого и все проблемы.

Проще всего не искать общих решений, а тупо создавать в программе  строку для вывода и выводить ее. Аналогично для ввода данных.

Для перекодировки в винде есть пара функций -  CharToOem() (ANSI -> cp866) и OemToChar() (cp866 -> ANSI).

**Пример программы**

```
--------------------------------------------------
/* cp1251-866.c
   Вывод русских букв (приветствие и аргументы командной строки) 
   в stdout (консоль или файл)
   Ввод русских букв с stdin (консоли или файла) и поиск их, как подстроки
   в приветствии (или последнем аргументе командной строки, если он был задан)
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

static char *
linget (char *str)
{
  char *p;

  printf("> "); fflush(stdout);
  if (p = fgets(str,1024,stdin))
    str[strlen(str)-1] = 0;
  return p;
}

main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char buf[1024];
  char out866 = isatty(fileno(stdout)),
    in866 = isatty(fileno(stdin));

  char *hello = "Привет !";
  if (out866 )
    CharToOem(hello,buf);  // AnsiToOem(hello,buf);
  else
    strcpy(buf,hello);
  printf ("%s out866 %s in866 %s GetConsoleCP %d GetConsoleOutputCP %d\n", buf, 
          out866? "YES" : "NO",
          in866? "YES" : "NO",
          GetConsoleCP(), GetConsoleOutputCP());

  int i;
  for (i = 1; i < ac; i++) {
    if (out866)
      AnsiToOem(av[i],buf); // CharToOem(av[i],buf);  
    else
      strcpy(buf,av[i]);
    printf ("arg[%d] : %s\n",i,buf);
    hello = av[i];
  }

  printf ("Enter lines for strstr() with \"%s\"\n", buf);
  fflush(stdout);
  while (linget(buf)) {
    if (in866)
      OemToAnsi(buf,buf);  // OemToChar(buf,buf);
    printf ("result of strstr() : %s\n",
            strstr(hello,buf) == NULL? "No":"Yes");
    fflush(stdout);
  }

  printf ("End\n");
  exit(0);
}

В эмуляторе (eshell в Emacs) это аналогично переключению stdin и stdout на файлы

c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ gcc cp1251-866.c 
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ ./a йцукен
Привет ! out866 NO in866 NO GetConsoleCP 866 GetConsoleOutputCP 866
arg[1] : йцукен
Enter lines for strstr() with "йцукен"
> qwe
result of strstr() : No
> цук
result of strstr() : Yes
> End
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $

В консоли (cmd)

C:\Users\avp\src\cc\hashcode>a
Привет ! out866 YES in866 YES GetConsoleCP 866 GetConsoleOutputCP 866
Enter lines for strstr() with "Привет !"
> bdtn
result of strstr() : No
> ивет
result of strstr() : Yes
> ^Z
End

C:\Users\avp\src\cc\hashcode>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. 
У меня что-то не получается так сделать..( 
Если я вписываю  строку CharToOem("ANSI", "cp866");
у меня программа вообще перестает запускаться...

Comment: @777Julia777, естественно. Вы вызываете  `CharToOem("ANSI", "cp866");` т.е. пытаетесь перекодировать символы "ANSI" и поместить их вместо **константы** с символами "cp866". 

**Это неправильно. Нельзя менять константы**.

Я дополню ответ примером. Что неясно - спрашивайте.

Comment: Спасибо, я сейчас попробую разобраться!..)