# fprintf как записать в файл латиницу?

Tags: c

Пытаюсь освоить запись в файл,числа и английский алфавит записываются нормально, но если пытаюсь записать кириллицу - в файле появляются какие-то иероглифы. Как можно это исправить? Файл txt.

Comment: Пример кода с входными данными и результатами в студию

Comment: @avp А что тут сбрасывать? Ну к примеру fprintf(test,"Тест");

Comment: Ну, раз не работает, значит ОС это винда. Наверное кто-то из специалистов в ней вам сейчас поможет со всеми настройками кодировок

Comment: Обычное несоответствие кодировок - пишете в одной, читаете в другой...

Comment: @Harry. И как это можно исправить? Я уже перепробовал все что знал

Comment: Чем вы смотрите внутрь файла? Какой программой? Кстати, интереса для запишите какой-то текст и выложите получившийся файл на какой-нибудь файлообменник - посмотреть... Кстати, еще гляньте сюда - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/198586/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb

Comment: @Harry. Ну к примеру Љ«оз иЁда®ў ­Ёп Ї® бв®«Ўж ¬ҐЁЄ«жп.  Смотрю через блокнот. Пытался менять кодировку блокнота на UTF-8 и юникод. Не помогло. Так же, что бы не использовать setlocale я прописал в настройках компилятора -fexec-charset=cp866 -finput-charset=cp1251. Может в этом проблема?

Comment: @Mr.Brown Почему это не было написано в вопросе? С такими параметрами, файлы будут выводиться в cp866. Скачайте себе какой-нибудь notepad++, и сможете без проблем читать их.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Нужно именно в обычном блокноте что бы считалось. Получается нужно изменить cp866  на cp1251 что бы блокнот принимал ?

Comment: Можно убрать оба параметра. Если в них написаны две одинаковые кодировки, то смысла в них мало. Для вывода в консоль тогда понадобится setlocale или что-то еще.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Можете продублировать это как ответ? Я отмечу как лучший,что бы другим было проще разобраться

Comment: @Mr.Brown Вопрос закрыт, ответ добавить невозможно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема с кодировкой. Думаю вам поможет:
`setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"ru");`

Comment: Пробовал,не работает

Comment: @Mr.Brown **не работает** - исчерпывающая информация :-) Что это значит в реальности? Я подозреваю, что Ваша программа пишет кириллицу в файл в одной кодировке, а Вы пытаетесь его смотреть какой-то другой программой, которая предполагает **другую** кодировку.

Можно - как то более конкретно описать ситуацию?

Comment: @Sergey Сохраняю в txt и смотрю в блокноте. Менял кодировку блокнота на ANCI,юникод и UTF-8. Не помогло. Прописывал setlocale-не помогло.

Comment: @Mr.Brown *Прописывал setlocale-не помогло.* - это должно помочь 100%, ЕСЛИ вы запускаете программу в том же самом сеансе, что и смотрите результат. У вас всё это безобразие творится под виндой, я так понимаю? Попробуйте так: 1) Откройте окно командной строки 2) Перейдите в папку, где лежит ваш ЕХЕ-шник и запустите его 3) Распечатайте результат командой... Ну, какая в винде есть КОНСОЛЬНАЯ команда просмотра файлов?